# nginx, apache http authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite, varnish, http-authentication

I have an nginx reverse proxy server which feeds into a varnish cache with an apache backend.

The php is running as a fastcgi process started from apache.

I was attempting to get some php software working however the basic HTTP Authentication dialog was not accepting any usernames or passwords. I did some digging around and came up with this to put in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

This has fixed the authentication issue with the basic HTTP auth.

Now I've been attempting to work out what exactly this has done, so my question is: why did adding this rewrite rule make the authentication start working?

All I could come up with at the moment is that somewhere along the chain of nginx -> varnish -> apache, apache was not recieving the auth headers. I would like to understand what is going on here so I can implement a change on the server level that will stop this from occuring elsewhere.

Can someone please clarify?

Thank you

Comment: "nginx -> varnish -> apache" -- i think you're doing it wrong.  putting varnish between apache and nginx defeats the whole purpose of varnish, unless you've ensured that your nginx has been setup to not do any disc-based buffering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosing track of HTTP Authentication seems to be not an issue of *nginx* or *Varnish*.

This rewrite rule is not for making *authentication* header fields accessible to *Apache* but to the *Fast-CGI* backend (assuming authentication should be recognized inside *PHP*).

*Authentication* headers are usually hidden from Fast-CGI. **You can**

- either use this `RewriteRule` hack to set the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable by hand;
- or the `mod_fastcgi` [configuration](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiServer) variable to pass headers to Fast-CGI:

> FastCgiServer:
> [...]
>
> `-pass-header header (none)`
>
> > The name of an HTTP Request Header to be passed in the request environment. This option makes available the contents of headers which are normally not available (e.g. Authorization) to a CGI environment
>
> [...]

Comment: This explains it clearly :)